# About a perfect FN-group

Tags: group-theory

the consept **perfect group** is new for me.

I was reading the following:

If a group $G$ is a FN-group and $G'=G$ then $G$ is finite.

I tried to prove this and here is my attempt:

let $G$ be a FN-group, then there existe a normal subgroup $N$ such that $N$ is finite and $G/N$ is nilpotent.
If we use the fact that if $G=G'$ then $G=Z(G)$ then $G/N$ is abelian, hence $G$ is finite by abelian, so $G'$ is finite. But $G=G'$ , so G is finite.

I am not sure if the result **$G=Z(G)$** holds.

Is my prove true or false.  Thank you

Comment: A homomorphic image of a perfect group is still perfect. So if $G$ is perfect and $ FN$, then $G/N$ is both perfect and nilpotent for the given finite normal subgroup $N$. Set $H = G/N.$ Then since the lower central series for $H$ terminates in the identity after finitely many steps, we must have either have $[H,H] \neq H$ or $[H,H] = 1.$ But $H$ is perfect,so $[H,H] = H$. Hence $[H,H] = H=1$, so that $N = G$ is finite.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson thank you very much, but  why if $\gamma _{c} (H)$ is finite for some $c$ then $[H,H] \neq H$ or $[H,H] =1$

Comment: If $\gamma_{2}(H) = H$ ( ie $[H,H] = H$), then we have $\gamma_{c}(H) = H$ for all $c \in \mathbb{N}.$ But $H$ is supposed to be nilpotent, so we have $\gamma_{c}(H) = 1$ for some $c$. Hence $H = 1$.